# Compartilhar enum de um web service com o client

Tags: c#, .net, web-service, enums, wsdl

Criei um web service onde tem enumeradores para manter o controle de um atributo do tipo inteiro, gostaria de saber como faço para ter acesso a este enumerador de outro projeto no qual estou utilizando esse web service.

Edit:

[image]

Comment: não seria só consumir o web services !!!

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Bom, pra mim não apareceu esses enumeradores. Tenho acesso ao métodos do web service, porém o enumerador não consegui acessar.

Comment: Certamente porque você não tem um método que devolva seu Enum ... se você esta em outra Solution.projeto.  então crie um Enum nesse outro projeto. Não faz sentido consumir um Enum por web services

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza adicionei a foto para melhor entendimento. Tenho o webservice e criei um enum dentro de uma pasta no projeto, do webservice eu acesso os enumeradores, basta referenciar o caminho, mas como faço para acessar de outro projeto?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza é pq é um enum do webservice, e não dessa outra solution.

Comment: Faz referencia da DLL no seu projeto.

Answer (score 1):

Como você não especificou qual linguagem você usa em sua apresentação, estou assumindo que você está suando alguma solução C#.

Desta forma, o que você tem que fazer é criar um projeto Web Application vazio.
Seria assim:

[image: Criando novo projeto para os enumerators]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: ## Você deve colocar seus enumerators neste pacote. ##]

Todos os seus enumerators, devem ficar neste biblioteca, desta forma basta apenas você referencial esta dll no projeto em que você quer fazer uso destes enumerators.

### Seria assim

[image: Menu referencia]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### No uso ficaria assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]